# how can i create Cover Flow application in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hey all,
        Anyone guide me that how can i create cover Flow application for an iphone. i am trying to cover some area but i can't understand about it. so please help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the first edition of Erica Sadun's 'iPhone Developer Cookbook' - it has an example there.

Comment: hey Mr.Alan , Thanks for your help but the code is too complex and i am new bee in developing so i can't understand how to develop it. do you have any tutorial about it.